# Get reviews by SKU and id using SQL query in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, database

I want a SQL query to get product reviews by SKU using **Magento2** for example,

It should contain,

```
SKU,id,title,discription,name
```

Please help me someone for the same.
since I am new to Magento 2.

Comment: Why not use product model to get it instead of sql query?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\Reviews\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection as ReviewCollection;

class Results
{
    /**
     * @var ReviewCollection
     */
    private $reviewsCollection;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $reviewsColFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $reviewsColFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $reviewsColFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->reviewsColFactory = $reviewsColFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // your code

        ############ function to load reviews by sku ################
        $sku = 'YOUR-SKU';
        $reviews = $this->getReviewsCollectionBySku($sku);
        ############ end - function to load reviews by sku ################

        // your code           
    }

    /**
     * @param string $sku
     * @return ReviewCollection
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getReviewsCollectionBySku(string $sku): ReviewCollection
    {
        if (null === $this->reviewsCollection) {
            //$sku = 'PRODUCT-1';
            $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);

            $this->reviewsCollection = $this->reviewsColFactory->create()
            //->addFieldToSelect(['detail_id', 'title', 'detail', 'nickname'])
            ->addStoreFilter(
                $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
            )->addStatusFilter(
                \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
            )->addEntityFilter(
                'product',
                $product->getId()
            )->setDateOrder();
        }
        return $this->reviewsCollection;
    }
}
```

This might do your work, it's NOT TESTED though. You can tweak this and do what you need to do. Un-comment the `addFieldToSelect` line in `getReviewsCollectionBySku` function to load the required fields. SKU of cause you already have at this point.

I wrote this based on below function in Magento core:

```
vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Product/View.php::getReviewsCollection
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with joins on below tables

Tables

**catalog_product_entity**

- entity_id
- sku

**review**

- review_id
- entity_id --> product entity id

**review_detail**

- review_id
- title
- detail
- nickname
- store_id --> if using multi store

**eav_attribute**

- attribute_id
- entity_type_id --> usually is equal to 4 for product entity
- attribute_code --> find out attribute id for product description, name

**catalog_product_entity_text (for description)**
**catalog_product_entity_varchar (for name)**

- attribute_id --> id from eav_attribute
- entity_id --> product entity id
- value
- store_id --> if using multi store

Answer (score 0):

You will need to join review & review_detail tables.

```
select r.review_id,sku,title,detail,nickname from review r
inner join catalog_product_entity p on p.entity_id = r.entity_pk_value
inner join review_detail d on d.review_id = r.review_id;
```